# _TypeError Exception on checking for null?

Tags: flutter, dart

(I'm new to dart but I have 25+ years of development experience in languages like C#, JS...)

Why can this exception happen? I makes no sense at this line... Checking for null should never throw a type exception. What is the reason behind this?

```
if (widget.columnDef.setEditValueFunc != null) {
```

[image: Exception occuring]

Declaration of setEditValueFunc is:

```
class CdItemsViewColumnDef<T> {
  late void Function(T, String)? setEditValueFunc;
  ...
```

setEditValue is set like this:

```
final List<CdItemsViewColumnDef<MyDataItem>> columnDefs = [];
columnDefs.add(CdItemsViewColumnDef<MyDataItem>(

  setEditValue: (item, value) => item.name = value,
  ...
```

Do I need to cast the null somehow?

---

Changing the declaration to

```
class CdItemsViewColumnDef<T> {
  late void Function(dynamic, String)? setEditValueFunc;
  ...
```

is solving the problem. But actually I would like to use T here...

Comment: I believe you are having this TypeError because you have declared "late void Function(T, String)? setEditValueFunc" but the value it gets is not of this type "Function(T, String)?" rather the data you are passing to it is of "(dynamic, String) => void, if you can ensure the data passed to setEditValueFunc is of the type "Function(T, String)?". Kindly let me know if this helps.

Comment: To resolve this issue while maintaining type safety, you can use a local variable to capture the non-nullable type: `var setEditValueFunc = widget.columnDef.setEditValueFunc;
if (setEditValueFunc != null) {}`

Comment: @Godson The data passed to setEditValueFunc is: setEditValue: (item, value) => item.name = value - and intellisense is invering item to be of type T (=MyDataItem)

Comment: @Dhruvil same error occurs on: var setEditValueFunc = widget.columnDef.setEditValueFunc;

Comment: @Godson Also not working is: (MyDataItem item, String value) => item.name = value

Comment: The error clearly happens not on that null checking line; where's the next step of that exception occurs?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan it is happening at this line - this is the strage thing...

Comment: If I write a function on class CdItemsViewColumnDef:   bool canEdit() { return setEditValueFunc != null; } the error is not occuring. In my eyes even more strange...???

Comment: If you press "Step Into" in the debugger, it's not bringing you anywhere?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan on Step into first thing happens is: class _TypeError extends Error implements TypeError {
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  _TypeError._create(this._url, this._line, this._column, this._message);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for this example i assumed your collection is `List`, but it can be any collection.

```
  final columnDefs = <CdItemsViewColumnDef>[];
  columnDefs.add(CdItemsViewColumnDef<MyDataItem>(
    setEditValue: (item, value) => item.name = value,
  ));
```

Causes problem as you define collection as `CdItemsViewColumnDef<dynamic>` and later on try to enforce different object type: `CdItemsViewColumnDef<MyDataItem>`

Depending on your use case:

#### Solution 1

```
  final columnDefs = <CdItemsViewColumnDef>[];
  columnDefs.add(CdItemsViewColumnDef(
    setEditValue: (item, value) => item.name = value,
  ));
```

This will be interpreted as collection of `CdItemsViewColumnDef<dynamic>`

#### Solution 2

```
  final columnDefs = <CdItemsViewColumnDef<MyDataType>>[];
  columnDefs.add(CdItemsViewColumnDef<MyDataType>(
    setEditValue: (item, value) => item.name = value,
  ));
```

This will be interpreted as collection of `CdItemsViewColumnDef<MyDataType>`

Obviously if you can you should always use strong typing (Solution 2), but if you would like to have dynamic type of the collection items, the whole collection has to be `List<dynamic>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already used Solution 2. Error still occurs. I Updated the question... Also with final List<CdItemsViewColumnDef<MyDataItem>> columnDefs1 = <CdItemsViewColumnDef<MyDataItem>>[]; it is not working.

Comment: Did you call `.add(` with strong typing `columnDefs.add(CdItemsViewColumnDef<MyDataType>(`? I don't have your problem- maybe the issue is in different place, try out my example:
https://gist.github.com/Jan-Stepien/2eb9c21305cc0d32b47c63015d956088

Comment: Thanks a lot for your sample and time! I found the problem in my code. See this gist: line 32 and 33 https://gist.github.com/mahop-net/c7ba3718a75f2d48ee58632ac055b84c Finally it was the same problem as this one I already had: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/3385#issuecomment-1751712082 which is basically discussed here: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/524